# C# access control in usercontrol after changing name

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have made this small loop to create multiple usercontrols. In these usercontrols are comboboxes which I want to change when pressing a button in the form, but I can't access them individually using the name I gave them.
Here's the for-loop I'm using for the usercontrols:

```
TournBox MatchBox;
        int i;
        int XCoordinate, YCoordinate;
        XCoordinate = 0;
        YCoordinate = 0;
        Teamcount = ((objDataSet2.Tables["dsTeams"].Rows.Count - 1) / 2);
        for (i = 0; Teamcount + 1 > i; i++)
        {
            MatchBox = new TournBox(objDataSet2.Tables["dsTeams"]);
            MatchBox.Name = "TRound" + i.ToString();
            MatchBox.Location = new Point(10 + XCoordinate , 10 + YCoordinate);
            MatchBox.Visible = true;
            this.pnlWinners.Controls.Add(MatchBox);
            foreach (DataRow dr in objDataSet2.Tables["dsTeams"].Rows)
            {
                MatchBox.CboTeam1.Items.Add(dr["Teamnaam"]);
                MatchBox.CboTeam2.Items.Add(dr["TeamNaam"]);
            }
            YCoordinate = YCoordinate + 63;

        }
```

I tried this and set the combobox in the usercontrol to public.:

```
private void btnTeamList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TRound1.CboTeam1.Items.Add("el jefe");
    }
```

Sorry for grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by name from the panel on which you added it:

```
this.pnlWinners.Controls["TRound1"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I access the combobox (CboTeam) inside the usercontrol (TRound1) to add an item?